# VB.NET: Declaration expected error when starting a new thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

```
Public Class Class1
    Dim thread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf AMethod)
    thread.Start()

    Public Sub AMethod()
        Console.writeline("Thread start") 
    End Sub
End Class
```

The "thread.Start()" is the problematic line, according to vb.
Declaring the thread in a sub gives an overload error, whatever that means.

Comment: You can't call a method directly in class definition. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @user6133226 You can't have shared variables in modules, and I need shared variables between methods.

Comment: that's not supposed to work anywhere - classes/modules are only supposed to contain **declarations** directly.

Comment: You cant have executable code just floating around like that.  `thread.Start()` needs to be inside a method (and thats not `Shared` and there is no `Module` there - words mean things)

Comment: @user6144226 Then how can I have two methods running different threads with variables shared between them?

Comment: @usernamesAreHard - frankly I'd start out with understanding the basic program structure enforced by a language before jumping into those.

Comment: Overload means there can be several methods with the same name and different number and/or types of arguments. If you don't have a match to one of the method overloads then you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't understand what @Plutonix meant by "executable code floating around" (I love that phrase) here is an example:

```
Public Class Class1
    Dim thread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf AMethod)

    Public Sub StartingThread()
        thread.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub AMethod()
        Console.WriteLine("Thread start")
    End Sub
End Class
```

See, the executable code thread.Start() is now inside a method. I, myself, am steering clear of threading until I know much more about it.